# How do i enforce all devs on a team to use the same flutter version?

Tags: flutter, azure-devops

On a team it is important to make sure nobody upgrades a project accidentally, or does any builds of any kind on an unexpected version of flutter, via pipeline or locally or any deployment channel.

https://github.com/passsy/flutter_wrapper/issues/30
https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/1845

Comment: You can limit SDK version: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints

Comment: @Jeppe this only works one direction. It prevents pub get and run from working if the local version is too low but not if it is too high.
in addition it still requires local management, passsy's solution bundles the version management. so there's two pieces.

Comment: passsy has a great idea to consider here https://github.com/passsy/flutter_wrapper/issues/30

Comment: Looks like there's an open issue on it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95472

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the Flutter version in the pubspec.yaml file under the "environment:" section. [Reference here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29211#issuecomment-494994579). Here is what my pubspec.yaml looks like (notice that the line for "sdk" is the Dart version):

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: 3.0.2
```

For example, if my local Flutter version is 3.0.1 and I specify 3.0.2, `pub get` outputs the following for me:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_project...                         
The current Flutter SDK version is 3.0.1.

Because my_project requires Flutter SDK version >=3.0.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because my_project requires Flutter SDK version >=3.0.2, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

But notice how the warning message says that my_project requires "greater than or equal to" instead of being pegged at precisely 3.0.2. I believe this is what Jeppe's comment refers to as an open issue.